# Confluent Kafka returns -1001 for offset position

Tags: c#, .net, apache-kafka, confluent-kafka-dotnet

I'm trying to get the `Kafka` offset using `Confluent Kafka`.

This is the code I'm using to obtain it:

```
var offsetPosition = consumer.Position(new TopicPartition(topicConfiguration.Topic, topicConfiguration.Partition));
```

It always gives me a value of -1001 though. What am I doing wrong?

**Additional Info**

I think this is may because it is `Unset`. This is what the doc says:

> Unset in case there was no previous message consumed by this consumer.

I'm not sure what I should do with this though.

Comment: Well, like the message says, it means that no one has consumed that topic partition and committed the offset. So by default it returns `Unset (-1001)`. What output are you expecting?

Answer (score 3):

You aren't doing anything wrong, that is the default value. From the docs:

> If an offset value of Offset.Invalid (-1001) is specified, consumption
> will resume from the last committed offset, or according to the
> 'auto.offset.reset' configuration parameter if no offsets have been
> committed yet.

If you want to specify where to start from, you can use the `consumer.Assign` method.

Comment: This should be the same for other languages btw, I found this while using the Python confluent_kafka client